# using the map function with timeit in Python

Tags: python, performance, function, dictionary, timeit

I am learning python and am looking at the difference in performance between using comprehension and the map function.

So far, I have this code:

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit('[x for x in range(100)]',number = 10000)

def mapFunc(i):
    print i

print timeit.timeit('map(mapFunc,range(100))',number = 10000)
```

After trying this, I have managed to get the list comprehension method to work correctly using timeit, however, I would like to compare this to the map function. When doing this, I get the error that mapFunc is not defined, and I do not know how to fix this issue. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You should *setup* the function definition via the `setup` argument:

```
>>> setup='def mapFunc(): print(i)'
>>> timeit.timeit('map(mapFunc,range(100))', number=10000, setup=setup)
```

See the [`timeit` doc reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit)

P.S. Probably not a good idea to use `map` for printing.

Comment: what does the third argument setup=setup mean?

Comment: note that with the `print` statement, it is pretty unfair to `map`

Comment: how could i improve this function to set this up properly? so if i shouldn't use print, what would i do instead?

Comment: @carlsaptarshi How do you mean: *set this up properly*?

Comment: so if i shouldn't use print, what would i do instead of using print?

Comment: Instead of using `map` on a function that only prints items, you're better off using a regular for loop in place of `map`

Comment: Another issue with `map` is that in Python 3, it only creates an iterator; it doesn't actually process all the items until you iterate over it. So you'd need a loop of some kind anyway.